# disable/ enable dynamically added input field by jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, disabled-input

problem 1:

The following code should enable/ disable an dynamically added input field by jquery, but it does not work as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#auto').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $('input[id="speed_car"]').prop('disabled', false).css('background', '').val('4')
        } else {
            $('input[id="speed_car"]').prop('disabled', true).css('background-color', '#03f').val('')
        }
    });
});
```

Problem2: If i save the field and reload the page it works, but only for the first < tr > (which contains other input fields and selects).

How should i change the code so that it will work correctly?

Here's part of the code which add's the  row:

```
  var modell = <?php echo $modell; ?>;
   .
   .
   .
  html += '    <td class="left"><select name="car_modell[' + modell + '][auto]">'; 
  html += '     <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>';
  html += '     <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>';
  html += '    </select></td>';
  html += '    <td class="left"><input type="text" maxlength="1" name="car_modell[' + modell + '][speed_car]" value="4" size="3" /> </td>'; 
  ecc...
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: just wondering, is input id speed_car unique? Is #auto change fired as expected? Could you provide a jsfiddle BTW?

Comment: that's one of the problem. it's always the same id. But i don't know how to write it in another way

Comment: so, easy way is to not use ID but class instead. You can still apply some context if needed. And what about change event, is it fired?

Comment: As roasted says, use a class not an id. IDs must be unique.

Comment: id or class will be always the same if the row will be added. Doesn't change. The problem is that the row's are added dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "on" function.  Look here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery Binds on Load, but the "on" causes it to evaluate/bind at that moment.

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```